# How do I improve the speed of this code? (Solving ODEs with scipy.integrate.odeint)

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve a relatively large ODE system with `scipy.integrate.odeint` module. I already implemented the code and I can solve the equation correctly. But the process is very slow. I profile the code and I realized that almost most of the computing time spent on computing or generating the ODE system itself, the sigmoid function is expensive too but I have to accept it I guess. Here is a piece of code that I'm using:

```
def __sigmoid(self, u):
    # return .5 * ( u / np.sqrt(u**2 + 1) + 1)
    return 0.5 + np.arctan(u) / np.pi

def __connectionistModel(self, g, t):
    """
        Returning the ODE system
    """
    g_ia_s = np.zeros(self.nGenes * self.nCells)

    for i in xrange(0, self.nCells):
        for a in xrange(0, self.nGenes):

            g_ia = self.Params["R"][a] *\
                     self.__sigmoid( sum([ self.Params["W"][b + a*self.nGenes]*g[self.nGenes*i + b] for b in xrange(0, self.nGenes) ]) +\
                     self.Params["Wm"][a]*self.mData[i] +\
                     self.Params["h"][a] ) -\
                     self.Params["l"][a] * g[self.nGenes*i + a]

            # Uncomment this part for including the diffusion
            if   i == 0:    
                g_ia += self.Params["D"][a] * (                           - 2*g[self.nGenes*i + a] + g[self.nGenes*(i+1) + a] )
            elif i == self.nCells-1:
                g_ia += self.Params["D"][a] * ( g[self.nGenes*(i-1) + a] - 2*g[self.nGenes*i + a]                             )
            else:
                g_ia += self.Params["D"][a] * ( g[self.nGenes*(i-1) + a] - 2*g[self.nGenes*i + a] + g[self.nGenes*(i+1) + a] )

            g_ia_s[self.nGenes*i + a] = g_ia

    return g_ia_s


def solve(self, inp):
    g0 = np.zeros(self.nGenes * self.nCells)
    t = np.arange(self.t0, self.t1, self.dt)
    self.integratedExpression = odeint(self.__connectionistModel, g0, t, full_output=0)
    return self.integratedExpression
```

As you could see in each iteration, I should generate nCells*nGenes (100*3=300) equations and pass it to the `odeint`. Although I'm not sure but I guess generating the equations is very expensive in comparison to solving them. In my experiment, solving the whole system takes 7sec which consists of 1sec of `odeint` and 6secs of `__ConnectionistModel`.

I was wondering if there is a way that I could improve this or not? I tried to use SymPy to define a symbolic ODE system and pass the symbolic equations to the `odeint` but it didn't works properly since you couldn't really define an array of symbols which later you could access like an array.

In the worst case, I have to deal with it or use a Cython to speed up the solving process, but I wanted to make sure that I'm doing it right and there is no way to improve it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

[Update]: profiling result,

```
    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.915    7.915 grnTest.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.554    7.554 grn.py:83(solve)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.554    7.554 odepack.py:18(odeint)
        1    0.027    0.027    7.554    7.554 {scipy.integrate._odepack.odeint}
     1597    5.506    0.003    7.527    0.005 grn.py:55(__connectionistModel)
   479100    1.434    0.000    1.434    0.000 grn.py:48(__sigmoid)
   479102    0.585    0.000    0.585    0.000 {sum}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.358    0.358 grn.py:4(<module>)
        2    0.001    0.001    0.207    0.104 __init__.py:10(<module>)
       27    0.014    0.001    0.185    0.007 __init__.py:1(<module>)
        7    0.006    0.001    0.106    0.015 __init__.py:2(<module>)
```

[Update 2]: I made the code publicly available: [pyStGRN](https://github.com/amirmasoudabdol/pyStGRN)

Comment: Profile your code better, be specific. Exactly where inside `__connectionistModel` you spend most time?

Comment: could you provide the `inp` input which gives this 7 second run?

Comment: @flebool I don't know how to profile inside a function to see which part is more expensive. But I included the profiling result.

Comment: I upload the code on GitHub - @will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectorize, vectorize, then vectorize some more. And use data structures that facilitate vectorization.

The function `__connectionistModel` uses a lot of the access pattern `A[i*m+j]`, which is equivalent to an access to row `i` and column `j` in a 2D array with a total of `m` columns. This suggests that a 2D array is the right way to store the data. We can eliminate the loop over `i` from the function by using the NumPy slicing notation and vectorizing as follows:

```
def __connectionistModel_vec(self, g, t):
    """
        Returning the ODE system
    """
    g_ia_s = np.zeros(self.nGenes * self.nCells)

    g_2d = g.reshape((self.nCells, self.nGenes))
    W = np.array(self.Params["W"])
    mData = np.array(self.mData)
    g_ia_s = np.zeros((self.nCells, self.nGenes))       

    for a in xrange(0, self.nGenes):
        g_ia = self.Params["R"][a] *\
            self.__sigmoid( (W[a*self.nGenes:(a+1)*self.nGenes]*g_2d).sum(axis=1) +\
                self.Params["Wm"][a]*mData +\
                self.Params["h"][a] ) -\
            self.Params["l"][a] * g_2d[:,a]
        g_ia[0] += self.Params["D"][a] * ( - 2*g_2d[0,a] + g_2d[1,a] )
        g_ia[-1] += self.Params["D"][a] * ( g_2d[-2,a] - 2*g_2d[-1,a] )
        g_ia[1:-1] += self.Params["D"][a] * ( g_2d[:-2,a] - 2*g_2d[1:-1,a] + g_2d[2:,a] )

        g_ia_s[:,a] = g_ia

    return g_ia_s.ravel()
```

As far as I can see, this returns the same values as the original `__connectionistModel`. As a bonus, the function is now more compact. I only optimized this function so that it has the same inputs and outputs as the original, but for extra performance, you might want to organize your data in NumPy arrays instead of lists so as to avoid the conversion from lists to arrays on every call. And I'm sure there are other minor performance tweaks as well.

Anyway, the original code gave me these profiling results (insert mandatory "my computer is faster than yours" brag here):

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1597    3.648    0.002    5.250    0.003 grn.py:52(__connectionistModel)
479100    0.965    0.000    0.965    0.000 grn.py:48(__sigmoid)
479100    0.635    0.000    0.635    0.000 {sum}
     1    0.017    0.017    5.267    5.267 {scipy.integrate._odepack.odeint}
  1598    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
```

With `__connectionistModel_vec`, I get:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1597    0.175    0.000    0.247    0.000 grn.py:79(__connectionistModel_vec)
  4791    0.031    0.000    0.031    0.000 grn.py:48(__sigmoid)
  4800    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
     1    0.018    0.018    0.265    0.265 {scipy.integrate._odepack.odeint}
  3197    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
```

Comment: That's great! I knew that I should do something like that but I didn't know how to do it. I even tried to use np.vectorize to vectorize the function but it didn't work as I was expected. -- @Jsl

Comment: From the `vectorize` doc: `The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`